# Why does std::ops:Mul not require a restriction on the Output type?

Tags: rust

In order to compile the code below I must specify the Output type of the Add operation. However, the very similar code using the Mul operation doesn't require this specification. Why is there a difference between the Add and Mul operations here?

```
trait IdentityExt {
    fn identity(self) -> Self;
}

impl<T> IdentityExt for T where T: std::ops::Mul, T: num::One {
    fn identity(self) -> T {
        self * T::one()
    }
}

trait IncrementExt {
    fn increment(self) -> Self;
}

//impl<T> IncrementExt for T where T: std::ops::Add, T: num::One { // Doesn't compile
impl<T> IncrementExt for T where T: std::ops::Add<Output = T>, T: num::One {
    fn increment(self) -> T {
        self + T::one()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let x = 13;

    println!("{:?}", x.increment()); 
    println!("{:?}", x.identity()); 
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=06f1e0462391409bfdff4391cd1b3df3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [`One`](https://docs.rs/num/0.2.1/num/trait.One.html) trait already do it, `pub trait One: Mul<Self, Output = Self>`. So, you can just write `impl<T> IdentityExt for T where T: num::One {`.

They add it because they want One to follow:

```
a * 1 = a       ∀ a ∈ Self
1 * a = a       ∀ a ∈ Self
```